# Incremental updates in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the most efficient way to append incremental updates in Spark SQL in Scala?

I have an employee dataframe `E1` which is archived with primary key `empId`.

I also have a latest employee dataframe and want to write only the updated, new and the deleted ones back to the archival dataframe.

For example:

Employee archived:

```
EmpId, EmpName
1      Tom
2      Harry
```

Employee recent:

```
EmpId, EmpName
2      Harry Lewis
3      Hermoine
```

Difference should return:

```
EmpId, EmpName, deleted
1      Tom         yes
2      Harry Lewis no
3      Hermoine    no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only wanted to find updated or new rows it would be possible to use `except`, however, since the deleted rows should be present it is a bit more complicated. Assuming `E1` is the archived employee dataframe and `E2` is the recent one, you can use a full join in Scala as follows:

```scala
E1.withColumnRenamed("EmpName", "EmpNameOld")
  .join(E2, Seq("EmpId"), "fullouter")
  .where($"EmpName".isNull || $"EmpNameOld".isNull || $"EmpName" =!= $"EmpNameOld")
  .withColumn("deleted", when($"EmpName".isNull, "yes").otherwise("no"))
  .withColumn("EmpName", coalesce($"EmpName", $"EmpNameOld"))
  .drop("EmpNameOld")
```

This will give you the wanted result, containing updated rows, new rows and deleted rows.